Article.current_transaction.after_commit outside of a transaction: whats the point?
In Rails 7.2, they introduce Article.current_transaction.after_commit, saying "for code that may run either inside or outside a transaction and needs to perform work after the state changes have been properly persisted", and they give the following code:
def publish_article(article)
  article.update(published: true)

  ActiveRecord.after_all_transactions_commit do
    PublishNotificationMailer.with(article: article).deliver_later
  end
end

My question is, isn't anything you do after the article.update(published: true) line only going to run after the transaction was committed anyway? Wouldn't it raise a Rollback exception if it wasn't committed? So what does wrapping PublishNotificationMailer.with(article: article).deliver_later inside a ActiveRecord.after_all_transactions_commit block even accomplish here? Why wouldn't you just have the code be:
def publish_article(article)
  article.update(published: true)

  PublishNotificationMailer.with(article: article).deliver_later
end


i think, the point is that you could also call publish_article from within another transaction.

ahhh that would make sense! and the difference doing the deliver_now inside a ActiveRecord.after_all_transactions_commit block as opposed to a current_transaction.after_commit block is that the later will run after the current transaction is committed, but if there are nested transactions or something the former will make it wait until all of them are committed?

It's kind of entertaining that the example they choose is also the one I would as an example of how not to use callbacks.
